# Move folder to parent folder and apppend parent name

Tags: powershell

I have folders that follow the pattern like this:

```
C:\
└───root
    ├───V16
    │   ├───1
    │   │       A.sql
    │   │       B.sql
    │   │
    │   ├───2
    │   │       C.sql
    │   │
    │   └───4
    │           E.sql
    │
    └───V17
        └───1
                D.sql
```

My goal is to obtain this pattern :

```
C:\root\V16-1\A.sql
C:\root\V16-1\B.sql
C:\root\V16-2\C.sql
C:\root\V17-1\D.sql
C:\root\V17-4\E.sql
```

I know perfectly how to do it in C # but unfortunately I am really newbie in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$DirToRemove=@()

Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\root\*\*" -directory | %{
    move-Item $_.FullName ($_.Parent.FullName + '-' + $_.Name)
    $DirToRemove+=$_.Parent.FullName
}

$DirToRemove | select -Unique | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

When moving folders the *.sql files are irrelevant.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\root\*\* -Directory |
  Move-Item -dest {'{0}\{1}-{2}' -f $_.PSParentPath.replace('\'+$_.Parent,''),$_.Parent,$_.Name} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remmove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Sample resulting tree:

```
C:\
└───root
    ├───V16
    ├───V16-1
    │       A.sql
    │       B.sql
    │
    ├───V16-2
    │       C.sql
    │
    ├───V16-4
    │       E.sql
    │
    ├───V17
    └───V17-1
            D.sql
```